# Determining relative path with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several wordpress sites installed in subfolders under a top level domain:

1. http://www.mydomain.com/site-a/
2. http://www.mydomain.com/site-b/

I need to load an AJAX file in each of them, and I've used the following code:

```
// Initiate asynchronous load of xml data:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
});
```

but that ends up searching for the file in the domain's root path:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml
```

Instead of the site's root path:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/site-a/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml
```

Comment: Get rid of the leading "/" in the url path. The leading slash means "from the root of the site", not "from my current folder".

Comment: That won't work if it's being loaded from a sub page- e.g. http://www.mydomain.com/site-a/page/ means it will point to http://www.mydomain.com/site-a/page/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml

Comment: If you can do some server scripting you can grab the current site and prepend it to your url path.

Comment: The URL it loads should be relative to the .js file it is run from, not the page you are using it on, unless you are running from an inline `<script>` tag for some reason.

Answer (score 33):

Get rid of the leading "/" in the url path. The leading slash means "from the root of the site", not "from my current folder".

Edit: Ok, then in the root index of each "site", you need to define BASE HREF to include that folder name. Then the leading slash should take into account that value instead of the site root.

Comment: That won't work if it's being loaded from a sub page- e.g. mydomain.com/site-a/page means it will point to mydomain.com/site-a/page/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml

Comment: @iKnowKingFoo- Can you clarify your edit- where do I define BASE HREF?

Comment: @iKnowKingFoo- Problem is that's no different than hardcoding the URL

Comment: @Yarin
localhost/A/B/C/
if your ajax page in B and the PHP file in C,
then u should put the url: "/A/B/C/file.php"
Because localhost is the BASE HREF.

Answer (score 13):

My best bet would be check location, like:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
```

And then do some indexOf() to specify which WP installation to point to.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you started your url with `/` that makes it an absolute url.  To make it a relative url change it to `url: "wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",`.

Comment: That won't work if it's being loaded from a sub page- e.g. mydomain.com/site-a/page means it will point to mydomain.com/site-a/page/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml

Comment: The URL it loads should be relative to the .js file it is run from, if you are using it in an inline `<script>` tag in one of the PHP pages you could use Wordpress' `home_url()` function: `url: "<?php echo home_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",`

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but would something like this work?

```
var baseUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com",
    pathToDataXml = "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    siteDir = window.location.href.toString()
              .replace(baseUrl, "")
              .replace(pathToDataXml, "");

// Initiate asynchronous load of xml data:
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: baseUrl + siteDir + pathToDataXml,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution:

```
url: window.location.pathname + "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
```

Answer (score 1):

If your javascript code is written within php file then use

```
url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
```

If calling AJAX request onclick from php file then use this in onclick

`onclick="cat_ajax_get('some_value', '<?php echo site_url(); ?>');"`

```
function cat_ajax_get(catID, ajaxurl) { 
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: ajaxurl + "/wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could define a global variable (I think this is justified in this case) defining the root directory:

```
rootFolder = location.pathname.substr(0, 7) === '/site-a' ? '/site-a/' : '/site-b/';
```

You could then use this variable for your AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: rootFolder + "wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: parseDataXML
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the window.location.pathname is noting to to with your directory structure. I admit that lots of the case it's work, but not always!
Just wrote it down because maybe somebody ended up here with MVC in her/his mind.

Answer (score -1):

I think what he is asking is if there is something like ms mvc Url.Content which will allow you to use ~/ to navigate to the sub-domain.  I don't think there is anything like that in jquery, or at least I haven't ran across it.  You may need to hard-code the subdomain into the url.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score -3):

You could simply use '..' before de folder name:

```
url: "../wp-content/themes/mytheme/data.xml"
```

I hope it works in wp. It usually works for other cases.