# request.isSecure() returns true when connection is http

Tags: java, ajax, http, jsp, https

I am trying to check if my url is http/https and then make an AJAX call to populate multiple dropdowns based on the value selected in the 1st dropdown.

```
var baseurl="<%=request.isSecure()%>";

if (baseurl=='true') {
    var url = 
        "https://<%=request.getServerName()%><%=request.getContextPath()%>/JsonLookup?z=" + zone;    
}
// if the protocol is 'http' 
else 
{   
    alert("inside protocol else");
    var url = "http://<%=request.getServerName()%><%=request.getContextPath()%>/JsonLookup?z=" + zone;  
    alert("inside http:"+url);
}
```

I have problem when the protocol is http, the dropdowns do not change. The reason is, base url (isSecure()) is always returning true even if it is http.

Can anyone help me solve this issue, what exactly am I supposed to do in order to make request.isSecure() return false for http?

Comment: In addition to this, I checked this on IE8, I see permission denied error.. here is the error details -                                           Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BTRS125042; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; BOIE8;ENUSMSCOM)
Timestamp: Fri, 14 Sep 2012 16:32:39 UTC


Message: Permission denied
Line: 544
Char: 2
Code: 0
URI: http://www.myurl.com

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use references without host name?

```
/path/to/resource
```

instead of

```
http://myserver.com/path/to/resource
```

EDIT:

Here's how your example will look like:

```
var url = "/<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JsonLookup?z=" + zone;
alert("My root relative URL: "+url); }
```

Comment: I am getting servername & path from variables. When building url I am hardcoding http and https separately. How do you think I should build url without specifying the hostname?

Comment: By the way I am using AJAX for populating the dropdowns when a value is selected in the 1st dropdown. When it comes to http, since the isSecure() still returns true, AJAX for the http://mylink does not work. I am still searching for a solution to my problem. Can any one please help?

Comment: But it won't be a problem if you omit `http` or `https` part. It's not necessary to use them. I'll expand my answer with an example.

Comment: Ivan, I used the relative path as you suggested. But the AJAx calls don't work for http/https in this case. On select of a dropdown value I am calling AJAX function where i am checking if http/https and then i am populating the subsequent dropdowns below the main dropdown.

Comment: *But the AJAx calls don't work for http/https in this case.* What do you mean by that? Do you need to return different set of results depending on whether it is `http` or `https`? If not then you absolutely don't need to check what protocol was used to do the call. Just remove any checks you had.

Comment: No,the result is the same if it is http/https. Now I am not checking for protocol, instead directly giving the relative path in the url.  But The dropdown values don't change at all (http/https) if I edit the code as you mentioned.

Comment: Then something else is wrong. Could you take a look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283000/determining-relative-path-with-jquery , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092352/relative-path-problems-in-javasvript-ajax-call

Comment: If I hardcode http /https only, then it works perfectly fine. Since people wanted to support both https/http usage in this code, I tried to include condition - isSecure(). I even tried out getScheme(). But both these functions do not seem to output false/ http at all in any case.

Comment: But, is there a way where I can check if my protocol is http or https in my JS function?  Since isSecure() and getScheme() doesnt seem to work for me as it always returns true/https.

Comment: @smiley Are you sure that you discard host name? Root-relative URL should not include it. I'm just trying to help and to tell you that putting anything starting with "http" into your HTML is a code smell (unless it's an external link). You can always do `eq.getRequestURL().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("https")`...

Comment: This is an existing code which supports http only for now. So , I am trying to make it work for https as well by putting the condition to check if it is http or https.

Comment: This is how I did now,   if (request.getRequestURL().toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("https"))
  {
  var url = "https://<%=request.getServerName()%><%=request.getContextPath()%>/JsonLookup?z=" + zone;
   }
  else
   {
    var url = "http://<%=request.getServerName()%><%=request.getContextPath()%>/JsonLookup?z=" + zone;
   } But it doesn't seem to pick it up at all :(

Comment: Sorry, it seems that something else is broken.

Comment: Still searching an answer for my question, so could not accept anyone's answers here.